# How to remove only 1 line with a certain string

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

Hi i have a question i have searched everywhere but i cant find it.

I want to use the sed command to remove a line containing a certain string. In the text file there are more lines with the same string . The sed command has to delete only the first string and not the rest. How can i do that can somebody tell me?
im gonna use it in a shell script wich will be activated multiple times till it runs out of the same string

For example i have the following lines:

```
aaa 
aaa 
aaa 
bbb 
ccc
```

and i only want to remove 1 line with aaa

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add information. Don't add it as comments

Answer (score 2):

It's more straightforward with `awk`:

```
awk '!/aaa/ || n++' < your-file
```

Which prints the current record if it does not contain `aaa` or, if it does, that the post-increment of some counter is non-zero (which it will be after the first occurrence).

With GNU `sed`, you can do:

```
sed '0,/aaa/{//d}' < your-file
```

Which only deletes a `aaa` line if it's in the range of lines from the beginning of the file to the first occurrence of `aaa`.

See the [sed FAQ](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq4.html#s4.11) for other possible approaches for non-GNU sed.